# How to align TextArea side by side in json schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema, react-jsonschema-forms

So I am trying to create a JSON schema for react using the react-JSON schema-form playground I am unable to find a way to put two TextArea side by side in the same row,[I can generate like this as of now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AUCSE.png),
[I need to generate something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Lykl.png)  , please refer to the images in the links attached,
any help would be much appreciated